# How to accomplish Server Certificate pinning in Azure?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, pinning

I have a Web API suite deployed in Azure managed by Azure APIM that transacts with an external API. I need to ensure that the Server Certificate from the external partner is validated and pinned before proceeding with any further transaction with the partner.

In the on-premises version of this solution I had the liberty to use a 3rd party product that gave me Firewall, API gateway and Server Certificate pinning features as a boxed solution.

What Azure service do I need to utilize to accomplish Server Certificate pinning?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with API management and mutual certificate management - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates